# How to do something only when route is the shortest path

Tags: ember.js

I want to have a specific behavior but only when my route is the last one.

For example, i have 
route 1: "posts.index"
route 2: "posts.index.show"

I want to do something in post.index if I'm calling it directly but I don't want to call it if I'm accessing posts.index.show directly. Is there a way to know if posts.index is the last state of the currently called routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only **leaf** routes are reachable, it means you can traverse node routes, but never stay on it finally.

In your case, `posts.index` will never be the final state of your router. I would recommend you to have something like:

```js
posts: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: 'posts',

  // connectOutlets as needed for layout purpose...

  collection: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/',

    // connectOutlets to render collection & so on...
  }),

  member: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/:id',

    // connectOutlets: here, you will at least store the instance for later use in children routes, and probably render its outlet

    show: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',

      // connectOutlets if needed.
    })

    // here, add other routes like edit, ...
  })
})
```

In the `member` route, you could have common processing (retrieve & render instance, at least), and then specialized according to leaf route, inside its `connectOutlets` function.